# How to boldify math equation and plain text simultaneously

Tags: math-mode, bold

We can boldify math equations using **\mathbf{}** and normal text using **\textbf{}**.

Suppose I want to boldify a line which contains both normal text and mathematical part simultaneously using a single command. Is it possible?

Let us consider the following example:

```
                          Since $s=9, s*s$ becomes 81
```

I have to do as follows

```
             \textbf{Since} $\mathbf{s=9, s*s}$ \textbf{becomes} 81
```

Instead of this, is there any newtag, that make whole text bold?

Comment: Do you want letters *and* symbols to be bold while in math mode, or just the letters? (`\mathbf` works only on letters.)

Comment: The input is incorrect: `Since $s=9$, $s*s$ becomes 81`. You need two formulas, not one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo can apply `\boldmath`:

[image]

Surrounding it with `{...}` limits the scope to be just within the curly braces so subsequent text is not effected.

### Notes:

- As per egreg's suggestion I have replaced `$s=9, s*s$` with `$s=9$, $s*s$`. The `,` is not really part of the math, thus, it should be outside.  This yields better spacing.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Since $s=9$, $s*s$ becomes 81

{\bfseries\boldmath Since $s=9$, $s*s$ becomes 81}

Since $s=9$, $s*s$ becomes 81

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please change the code `$s=9, s*s$` into `$s=9$, $s*s$`?

Comment: @egreg: Good point. Have corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Run with `lualatex` or `xelatex

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[version=bold]{xits-mathbold.otf}
\newcommand\allBold[1]{{\bfseries\mathversion{bold}#1}}
\newcommand\allbold[1]{{\bfseries\boldmath#1}}
\begin{document}

Since $s=9, s*s$ becomes 81 $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x$

\allbold{Since $s=9, s*s$ becomes 81 $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x$}

\allBold{Since $s=9, s*s$ becomes 81 $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x$}

Since $s=9, s*s$ becomes 81 $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x$
\end{document}
```

[image]